# In what file a C function is defined?

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking, shared-libraries

Let's say I want to call a C function: `printf`, `getpid`, `socketpair` or any other standard C function from my code in Assembly language. I know how to do that in terms of implementation. However, I'll also have to know where one of those functions defined -- in what Linux file, so that I can pass the name of that of that file to the linker. I think it should be a "so" file. How would I find out in what file it's defined?

**Note** that my question is general and the functions I've mentioned above are just an example. How would I know in what Linux library any arbitrary C function defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I find out what linker flags are needed to use a given C library function?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277845/how-can-i-find-out-what-linker-flags-are-needed-to-use-a-given-c-library-functio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a standard C library function, `libc.so` is probably correct.

If it's another library, *that library's documentation should tell you*. Eg. the manpage for `pthread_create` says

> Compile and link with `-pthread`

and you then need to look at the GCC documentation to see what it does with that option (eg, `-lpthread` plus some other stuff, so you want `libpthread.so`).

With third-party libraries, the onus is entirely on the library developer/distributor to tell you where to find the symbols listed in their API.

Worst case you can just `find` all `.so` files under `/usr`, `/lib`, `/opt` or wherever else you have libraries installed, and run `nm -D` on them. You're looking for entries of type `t` or `T`.

Note we're assuming that you only want shared objects (dynamic libraries) - if you're talking about arbitrary third-party libraries, they could equally ship static (`.a`) archives.

Comment: Note that it is just as difficult to know which library to link to a C program. If the function is not in the C standard library, which is linked by default, you will just have to know from documentation which library to link. Also note that you can use the `gcc` driver program to compile assembly programs too. Let's say your assembly code is in file `hello.s` and you call the `printf` function. Compile with `gcc -o hello hello.s` to produce the executable file `hello`. The `gcc` program does the linking for you, just as with a C program.

Answer (score 2):

These (`printf, getpid, socketpair`) are all part of the standard C library. That's the library that gets automatically linked to every C program.

I think the easiest way to solve your problem would be to link it with gcc, which will call the linker and link the appropriate version of the standard C library in.

If you want to proceed your way:

```
echo 'int main(){ }' |gcc -x c - && ldd ./a.out |grep libc
```

should give you the `so` file. In my case it's:

```
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc3a2b46000)
```

There's no generic solution for function `x` as far as I know.
You'd have to google to map a function to a library. If the library uses a library specific prefix instead of bare names (like the standard C library unfortunately does in most cases), googling it should be fairly unambiguous. (After that, you'd need to find where the library's SO file is on your system.)

Comment: that's not what I'm asking about.

Comment: libc.so is the shared object containing the C standard library. So, answering "the C standard library" - given the .so path is also shown - seems pretty reasonable

Comment: `There's no generic solution for function x as far as I know.` -- and not in manuals either?

Comment: Well sure, function x will be listed in the manual for whatever library it is contained in - but if you don't know what library, how will you know what manual?  Also, it's entirely possible that two or more different libraries define functions named x that do completely different things.

Comment: @Useless, for you?

Comment: @NateEldredge, "man socket" or "man some_function". But where exactly in "man some_function"? I haven't seen that  in "man" so far.

Comment: The standard library has a man page for each function it defines, but most third-party libraries do not.  They tend to have a separate documentation file instead (if they have documentation at all).  So that doesn't help.

Comment: If you want to limit yourself to installed libraries, you can always get all of them (for dynamic libraries, do `ldconfig -p`) and then get the symbol table of each (`nm -D` to get the dynamic symbol table) and then create a database mapping symbols to filenames.